# How to make this code identify what has been input before?

Tags: python

For a homework assignment we have to write code that will do the following:

> Write a program to read in multiple lines of input until a blank line
>   is entered. Each line of input will consist of multiple words. If you
>   have seen the word before, you should print it out. After the user has
>   finished entering input, your program should print out how many
>   repeated words it saw.

So far I have done this:

```
lineList = []
wordList = []
count = 0

line = input("Words: ")
while line:
  for x in line.split():
    if x in lineList:
      count += 1
      wordList.append(x)
      print(x)
      lineList.append(line)
      line = input("Words: ")

print('You repeated '+ str(count) +' word(s).')
```

My code doesn't loop back to the beginning, and it just stops. There is no error; the thing just stops running. What can I do to make it run again, and how do I make it work?

Comment: Did you input a word when prompted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, you have an infinite loop.  `line` is never updated with any values, since the condition that it's hiding under is never true.  `lineList` won't contain `x` at the beginning of the program, so it's just going to be stuck there.

The obvious fix to that would be to move the `input` line again over a couple of spaces...

```
while line:
  for x in line.split():
    if x in lineList:
      count += 1
      wordList.append(x)
      print(x)
      lineList.append(line)
  line = input("Words: ")
```

...but that doesn't quite do it either.

Your next problem is that your condition is incorrect.  You shouldn't care if a word appears in `lineList` - in fact, it's a superfluous variable that would only serve to confuse you later.  You want to be checking against `wordList`.

So, that makes the code this (without `lineList`):

```
line = input("Words: ")
while line:
  for x in line.split():
    if x in wordList:
      count += 1
    wordList.append(x)
    print(x)
  line = input("Words: ")
```

The last condition - the word should be echoed only if you've seen it before - I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply :) Got it completely right!

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that it stops, it's the opposite: it keeps going in an infinite loop, without asking for input, because it only asks for more input when and if it finds a word that's already in the `linelist`. Unindent the request for input by two levels, so that you ask for input after processing an entire line. You also have to add to the count and print the word if it *is* in the list, or add it to the list if it is *not* already in the list. You also have to add the word to `wordList`, not `lineList`. In fact, you don't need `lineList` for anything, either.

```
wordList = []
count = 0

line = input("Words: ")

while line:
    for x in line.split():
        if x in wordList:
            count += 1
            print(x)
        else:
            wordList.append(x)
    line = input("Words: ")

print('You repeated', str(count), 'word(s).')
```